# GO: Permission denied to file after installing gorilla

Tags: go, gorilla

I am new to SO and a relatively new beginner to GO. I was building and running GO code smoothly on my local server until I had to use some of the packages from Gorilla toolkit.

What I ran in the command line:

```
mkdir $HOME/mygo
export GOPATH=$HOME/mygo
cd mygo

go get github.com/gorilla/mux
```

I did this based on the example from here: http://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html. Under gettng started with the Go Command and here http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/.

After this, I imported my main.go code into the mygo folder. My directory folder looks like this:

```
Workspace
    pkg
    src
    main.go
```

However, when I ran go build main.go, and tried to run ./main, I got

```
-bash: ./main.go: Permission denied
```

What is happening?? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Go source code is not executable on its own. You need to compile it. Start here: http://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: I never had this problem until I ran go get github.com/gorilla/mux though. I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: I guarantee that didn't work before. For one thing, you can't execute go source code, nor can the shell interpret it. The message you have is the exact output from bash if you try to execute a non-executable file named `mycode.go`.

Comment: I would run go build main.go, and later ./main.go. That compiled and worked. Please see the second last line in my question.

Comment: If you run `go build main.go`, it outputs a binary called `main`, and nothing else, and you can run it via `./main`

Comment: that is what I did but like I said it was only when I install gorilla that I suddenly cannot run them. I want to know why.

Comment: According to your output, you are *not* executing `main`, you are trying to execute `main.go`. I can't help more without knowing the source of main.go. If you're struggling with this, I strongly suggest that you start with the link I provided first, or the [Tour Of Go](http://tour.golang.org/)

Comment: Ohh thanks so much. I don't know why I ran it like this. Anyway, its an oversight Thanks again

Comment: Note that the *proper* location to put your code is within the `src` folder, not next to it. Ideally under a folder with a project name.  http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I highly recommend reading http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php, then going through the Go [tour](http://tour.golang.org/).

Second, like @JimB mentioned, you can't execute `main.go` directly like that (you can use [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) but I'm not gonna explain that here).

So the steps to run your executable are:

```
go build -o main
./main
```

Or directly:

```
go run main.go
```